# Select rows where the combination of two columns is unique and we only display rows where the first column is not unique

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have an order line table that looks like this:

| ID | Order ID | Product Reference | Variant |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Banana | Green |
| 2 | 1 | Banana | Yellow |
| 3 | 2 | Apple | Green |
| 4 | 2 | Banana | Brown |
| 5 | 3 | Apple | Red |
| 6 | 3 | Apple | Yellow |
| 7 | 4 | Apple | Yellow |
| 8 | 4 | Banana | Green |
| 9 | 4 | Banana | Yellow |
| 10 | 4 | Pear | Green |
| 11 | 4 | Pear | Green |
| 12 | 4 | Pear | Green |

I want to know how often people place an order with a combination of different fruit products. I want to know the `orderId` for that situation and which `productReference` was combined in the orders.

I only care about the product, not the variant.

I would imagine the desired output looking like this - a simple table output that gives insight in what product combos are ordered:

| Order ID | Product |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | Banana |
| 2 | Apple |
| 4 | Banana |
| 4 | Apple |
| 4 | Pear |

I just need data output of the combination `Banana+Apple` and `Banana+Apple+Pear` happening so I can get more insight in the frequency of how often this happens. We expect most of our customers to only order `Apple`, `Banana` or `Pear` products, but that assumption needs to be verified.

**Problem**

I kind of get stuck after the first step.

```sql
select orderId, productReference, count(*) as amount
from OrderLines
group by orderId, productReference
```

This outputs:

| Order ID | Product Reference | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Banana | 2 |
| 2 | Apple | 1 |
| 2 | Banana | 1 |
| 3 | Apple | 2 |
| 4 | Apple | 1 |
| 4 | Banana | 2 |
| 4 | Pear | 3 |

I just don't know how to move on from this step to get the data I want.

Comment: Why order_id 1 and 3 are not appearing in the output?

Comment: @lemon Because they don't have different products

Comment: *I only care about the product, not the variant.* why then is the variant even in your sample data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a window `count() over()`

```
select * 
from
(   
    select orderId, productReference, count(*) as amount
       , count(productReference) over(partition by orderId) np
    from OrderLines
    group by orderId, productReference    
) t
where np > 1
```

Answer (score 3):

You need only the rows where an Order_Id has different products; you can do this many ways.

One way is to aggregate and filter to only rows where the min product <> the max product, then use a correlation to find matching orders:

```
select distinct t.Order_ID, t.Product_Reference
from t
where exists (
    select *
    from t t2
    where t2.Order_ID = t.Order_ID
    group by order_id
    having Min(Product_Reference) != Max(Product_Reference)
);
```

See this [demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6TKtNHLO)

Answer (score 0):

You could use STRING_AGG:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Here's an example:

```
SELECT orderID, STRING_AGG(productReference, ' ') products
FROM  
    ( 
      SELECT DISTINCT orderID, productReference
      FROM orderLines        
    ) order_products
GROUP BY orderID
```

For each order ID, this pulls out the distinct products, then the STRING_AGG combines them into one field.

**Output**

| orderID | products |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Banana |
| 2 | Apple Banana |
| 3 | Apple |
| 4 | Apple Banana Pear |

SQL fiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8a677/6